# SQL Injection Authentication Bypass Question

Tags: php, mysql, sql, code-injection

I will make this short and go straight to the point.

I am testing SQLI Login bypass on a PHP Code I have made below.

```
if(isset($_POST["login"]) && isset($_POST["password"])){


$sql="select * from users where login='{$_POST["login"]}' and password='{$_POST["password"]}'";


$result=mysqli_query($conn, $sql);


if(mysqli_num_rows($result) != 0)
    echo "<h1>Login Success!</h1>";


else
    echo "<h1>Invalid Login!</h1>";


}
```

I am using **admin' --** as the login field in order to successfully bypass login without entering  a password.

But the problem is it doesn't work but when I tried using this **admin' -- ' --** instead it works.

So question is how and why does that particular cheat sheet works instead but not the first one?

This **admin' -- ' --** works but not this **admin' --**

These are the server-side code when I enter these 2 cheat sheets.

The bypass that doesn't work.

```
$sql="select * from users where login='admin' --' and password='{$_POST["password"]}'";
```

The bypass that works.

```
$sql="select * from users where login='admin' -- ' --' and password='{$_POST["password"]}'";
```

Just need some clarification or explanation on how and why the 1st cheat sheet doesn't work but the 2nd one works. Thank you!

Comment: You have an obvious syntax error as the syntax highlighting shows

Comment: Topicstarter check the duplicate link i've explained in pretty great detail (tutorial style) there how to do a SQL injection for MySQL and MariaDB.

Comment: I have got this error for inputing admin' -- in the login field

**Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in**

Comment: That message means that you've mistyped something in your SQL query, like you're trying to select a column that doesn't actually exist.

Comment: Please write mysql keywords in all UPPERCASE for readability.  Also, `isset()` can receive multiple parameters -- you only need on `isset()` call.

Comment: Hello Guys apparently I found the solution.

the double dash operator comment requires a space after it.

So it will be  **where login='admin' -- '** instead of **where login='admin' --'**

Comment: I was able to bypass the login with a space after the double dash comment operator.

But the problem is why does this SQL query works instead 

**where login='admin' -- ' --'** is there any syntax explanation to this?

Comment: I think it actually works because its the same as the first SQL query is has space after double dash comment operator instead?

which is this one I am talking about **where login='admin' -- '**  , so this SQL query would work then **where login='admin' -- ' --'** if you look closely it already has a space after the comment operator.

Comment: Here is the source which I research about the comment operator. My bad for not researching about it.

http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-comment/

Comment: Feel free to verify my understanding. Correct me if I am wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You have some real syntax errors in your code:

First: don't do something like this: `$sql="select * from users where login='{$_POST["login"]}' and password='{$_POST["password"]}'";`

The correct way is to create a variable that is equals to the value of login and password. Example:

```
$login=$_POST['login'];
$password=$_POST['password'];
```

After this, your query should look like this:

```
$sql="select * from users where login='$login' and password='$password'";
```

Comment: I tried using that way for my SQL query its the same though.


admin' --  still couldn't bypass the login.

Comment: It's not incorrect to include the post variable directly. It's only another way for the same semantics. Anyway, both syntax forms allow SQL injections and clear text passwords.

Comment: Hello Guys apparently I found the solution. the double dash operator comment requires a space after it. So it will be where login='admin' -- ' instead of where login='admin' --' –

Comment: I was able to bypass the login with a space after the double dash comment operator.

But the problem is why does this SQL query works instead 

**where login='admin' -- ' --'** is there any syntax explanation to this?

Comment: I think it actually works because its the same as the first SQL query is has space after double dash comment operator instead? which is this one I am talking about where login='admin' -- ' , so this SQL query would work then where login='admin' -- ' --' if you look closely it already has a space after the comment operator.

Comment: Here is the source which I research about the comment operator. My bad for not researching about it.

http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-comment/

Comment: Feel free to verify my understanding. Correct me if I am wrong. Thanks!